# Share updated meta on facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a javascript updating description meta tag with a variable

```
$('meta[name=description]').attr('content',sharewhatever);
```

But the problem is that facebook cache is still going to have the old description if that page was shared before. Is there any way to deal with it without server side coding?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, any client side manipulation will not work as FB crawls your page when you try to share a page to grab the meta description. Hence, it would only find the meta tags/content that were loaded with the page. So, your best bet is to set appropriate meta content server side.